# Ошибка в консоли Unity 2019.4.1 при запуске сцены

Tags: c#, unity3d

при запуске проекта на Unity в консоль выводится сообщение с ошибкой -

> A PreviewRenderUtility was not clean up properly before assembly reloading which lead to leaking this scene in the Editor. This can be caused by not calling Cleanup() during the OnDisable of an Editor or an EditorWindow.
> UnityEditor.PreviewRenderUtility:Finalize()
> Подскажите пожалуйста с чем это связано, поиски в интернете ничего существенного не дали.
> Заранее спасибо.

Comment: судя по ошибке, тебе нужно вызвать метод Cleanup() в событии OnDisable вручную?

Comment: А в каком классе/компоненте может находиться данное событие, не подскажете?...я просто новичок в unity